# Is $M:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R} ; x^2=y^3\}$ a $C^{\infty}$-manifold?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

As I mentioned in the title, (I know $M$ is a topological manifold, but) I'm not sure if $M$ is $C^{\infty}$.

The definition of $M \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ being $m$ dimensional $C^{\infty}$ manifold is as follows:

There exists an open neighborhood  $U$ and a map $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^{N-m}$ for all $p \in M$, and $d_p f$(directional derivative at p) is surjective and $M\cap U =\{ p \in U;f(p)=0 \}$

Comment: sorry, \mayhbb →\mathbb

Comment: You can edit it yourself next time...

Comment: why are you asking more or less the same question twice within just some minutes?